# Pirateplayer Not able to install, old repository for Qt desktop components!

Tags: 12.10, repository, qt

I have a slow connection so I used to have pirateplayer to download programs from svt.se
but after update to Ubuntu 12.10 it wont be able to install. It wont compile
because the repository only updated for Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise" Is there some way I can use the files in Precise repository instead?

Edit:  The failing PPA is ppa:forumnokia/fn-ppa - it should be related to Qt desktop components as I understand from a contact with the developer of the application.

Here are the instruction from the website http://pirateplay.se/player.html:

```
wget "http://pirateplay.se/static/tidy-html5_20120402-1git-1_i386.deb"
wget "http://github.com/downloads/jackuess/pirateplayer/pirateplayer_0.4.5-1_i386.deb"
sudo aptitude remove tidy
sudo dpkg -i tidy-html5_20120402-1git-1_i386.deb
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:forumnokia/fn-ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude install qt-components-desktop libqtcore4 libqt4-declarative libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtgui4 libqt4-xml libqt4-network librtmp0 ffmpeg libarchive
sudo dpkg -i pirateplayer_0.4.5-1_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency that will be missing from that repository is `qt-components-desktop`. [Here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qtplayground/qtdesktopcomponents/commits/qt4)'s the source for Qt Desktop Components. It contains compile instructions in the Readme, and should be easy enough to compile in 12.10. `dpkg` will still complain about `qt-components-desktop` missing but it should still work if disabling dependency checks. A cleaner way to do it, than removing dependency checks, would be using [Checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) to make a `qt-components-desktop` package.